# XNA content.load Dependancy

Tags: xna

The project I'm building for test purposes is working fine but I have dependencies flying around everywhere due to the XNA framework.

My issue is in the content.load textures/sounds/fonts.
I have them as public variables (i.e.
`Texture1 = Content.load(of texture2d)("Texture1")` )

I'm passing a 'Game1' pointer into the constructor of every new class being instantiated to gain access to these variables.

**Am I missing an OOP trick that would prevent me having to pass a pointer to 'game1' to every New class?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the *simplest* way is just to add a public static reference to your game object, and assign it in the constructor. Has some similarities with using a singleton, but without all the restrictions:

```
public class Game1 : Game {
    public static Game1 Instance;
    public Game1() { Instance = this; }
}
```

After which you can easily access it from anywhere, such as  `Game1.Instance.Texture1`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know something about [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern? You can create for example GetGameObject function in some file, where you create your game object. This function will return game object (which is created only once).

Comment: Cheers Zach. I have thought of the singleton pattern, but much like a trigger in SQL it feels like a hack/workaround and thus i dismiss it without thinking.I might try it out. This is a good article :http://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/singleton-considerations/ ..... was thinking of a separate content class classed called say 'GameContent' using an interface. My objects are dependant on 'game1' but i want it to be loosely coupled.